# Phone numbers won't save

Tags: backup

My Samsung-g890a phone worked great until about a month ago, now when I put a phone number into my contacts, it stays for a short period of time but the disappears. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems to be that your settings has changed, you probably store the numbers under one default account (gmail, hotmail , yahoo) and you display another.

Try to save a number and check under wich account are you saving, then check with account are you displaying.